# Command Expression for active debug session?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-pde

I added the extension point `org.eclipse.ui.menus` to create a new button in the debug view.

That works perfectly, but this particular button is now always visible. How can I add a `visibleWhen` condition that checks if a debug session is currently running?

I checked the [Command Core Expressions](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Command_Core_Expressions), but did not find any expressions that may work in that case.

Answer (score 1):

The menus in the `org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui` plugin use expressions like this:

```xml
<visibleWhen
      checkEnabled="false">
   <and>
      <systemTest
           property="org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui.debuggerActive"
           value="true">
      </systemTest>

      ... other tests ...

    </and>
</visibleWhen>
```

Comment: Thanks Greg. I forgot to mention that I am using CDT and I guess that's why it does not work in my case (I thought that the debug view is completely independent from CDT). So, do you know how to do this in CDT?

Comment: I don't know anything about CDT.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good example project in CDT on how to get started customizing DSF. Please have a look at it's [`plugin.xml`](https://git.eclipse.org/c/cdt/org.eclipse.cdt.git/tree/dsf-gdb/org.eclipse.cdt.examples.dsf.gdb/plugin.xml#n91) and follow the uses of the command id defined there: `org.eclipse.cdt.examples.dsf.gdb.command.showVersion`

Here is one of the `visibleWhen`'s from that code.

```
        <visibleWhen
              checkEnabled="false">
           <and>
              <reference
                    definitionId="org.eclipse.cdt.debug.ui.testIsDebugActionSetActive">
              </reference>
              <with variable="org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform">
                 <test property="org.eclipse.core.runtime.bundleState"
                    args="org.eclipse.cdt.examples.dsf.gdb"
                    value="ACTIVE">
                 </test>
              </with>
           </and>
        </visibleWhen>
```